# Finding parameters using two data sets for the same ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, mathematical-modeling, parameter-estimation

I have to fit data to a system of two differential equations in order to estimate parameter values.
The model is on pathogen and cell interaction.

The ODE system is:

${dA\over dt}=r_1 A-p A(1-{B\over k_2})+eB$

${dB \over dt}=r_2 B + p A(1-{B\over k_2}) -e B$

Here A are the pathogens that are outside of cells, B are the pathogens that are within cells.

I want to estimate the values of $r_2$ (replication rate of pathogen inside the cell), e (exit rate of pathogen from the cell) and p (rate in which pathogens are internalized within cells). The other parameters are known constants.

To estimate these, I have found some data from an article.  They have measured the pathogen load exiting from the cells (from which I can find the exit rate ‘e’) and they have also plotted the entire pathogen population over time continuously as well (which includes pathogen replication, internalization, exit all).

The data that have measured exit are given as the total that exited over a time period of 2 hours. So for example data are like from 10-12 hours $10^3$ exited, 12-14 hours $10^5$ exited likewise.

So, when fitting these data to estimate the parameters I want to estimate ‘e’ from the data that shows the number of pathogen that exited over two hour time periods and the other parameters $r_2,p$ from the other data which shows the pathogen load over time.

I can’t first fit only to the exited data because then I don’t know $r_2$ and p.

So, how can I fit the ODE system for the two data sets simultaneously to estimate the three parameters.

In Matlab I know how to fit an ODE system to estimate parameters based on single data set, but I am finding it difficult to think how I can implement this kind of scenario.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the data ? Is it numerical values of $A$ as a function of numerical values of $t$ ? Or what else. Do not use words such as "pathogen load exited", only the symbols which are in your two equations. Alternatively, editing the data should be less ambiguous.

Comment: @JJacquelin One of the data I have is $-e*B$ which is measured as the pathogens exited at a 2 hour time period. The other data is A and B over time.

Comment: I may not have understood this but here goes anyway. If you have data points for $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ then you can estimate their derivatives by interpolation.   Add the two equations to get an equation in the one unknown $r_2$ which can be estimated by standard linear regression techniques. Use a similar procedure to estimate $p$ just using first equation.

Comment: If I well understand: $k_1$ doesn't exist, the values of the parameters $r_1$ and $k_2$ are known and you already can find the value of the parameter "$e$". So only two parameters are unknown : $r_2$ and $p$. OK ?

Comment: @JJacquelin $k_1$ does not exist and $r_1$ and $k_2$ are known. The values that I want to estimate are $e,r_2 $ and $p$. The issue is although I have data on $-eB$ I can't directly fit into those data without knowing $r_2$ and p. So, I have to use both data simultaneously. The next issue is data on $-eB$ are the accumulated data over a 2 hour period. So its not  say at 10th hour. Its the total exited $(-eB)$ during 10-12 hour period.

Answer (score 1):

${dA\over dt}=r_1 A-p A(1-{B\over k_2})+eB$

${dB \over dt}=r_2 B + p A(1-{B\over k_2}) -e B$

Sum of the two equations :

${d(A+B)\over dt}=r_1 A+r_2B$

$$y(t)=\frac{d(A+B)}{ dt}-r_1 A=r_2B$$

${d(A+B)\over dt}$ can be evaluated from numerical differentiation (see below).

So, there is only one unknown $r_2$ to be evaluated thanks to linear regression.

If the data consists in  : $\quad\begin{cases} A_1,A_2,...,A_k,...,A_n \\ B_1,B_2,...,B_k,...,B_n \\t_1,t_2,...,t_k,...,t_n\end{cases}$
$$\left(\frac{d(A+B)}{ dt}\right)_k \simeq \frac{A_{k+1}+B_{k+1}-A_{k+1}-B_{k-1} }{t_{k+1}-t_{k-1}}$$

For $\quad k=2\quad\text{to}\quad k=n-1\quad$ compute $\quad y_k=\frac{A_{k+1}+B_{k+1}-A_{k+1}-B_{k-1} }{t_{k+1}-t_{k-1}}-r_1A_k$

Least square fitting to $\quad y(t)=r_2B(t)$ :
$$r_2\simeq \frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}y_kB_k}{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(B_k)^2}$$

NOTE :

The numerical computation of derivatives is subjected to important deviation if the scatter of the data is large. So, it is not the best method.

The numerical integration is much more robust.

$$Y(t)=A+B-r_1\int Adt=r_2\int B dt$$
Starting from $I_1=0$, compute $$\quad I_k=I_{k-1}+\frac12 (B_k+B_{k+1})(t_{k+1}-t_k)\quad\text{from}\quad k=2\quad\text{to}\quad k=n$$

Starting from $J_1=0$, compute $$\quad J_k=J_{k-1}+\frac12 (B_k+B_{k+1})(t_{k+1}-t_k)\quad\text{from}\quad k=2\quad\text{to}\quad k=n$$

Then compute : 
$$Y_k=A_k+B_k-r_1J_k$$
Least square fitting to $\quad Y(t)=r_2B(t)$ :
$$r_2\simeq \frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}Y_kB_k}{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(B_k)^2}$$

Coming back to :

$p (1-{B\over k_2})A-eB=-{dA\over dt}+r_1 A$

$p (1-{B\over k_2})A -e B={dB \over dt}-r_2 B$

where $r_1,r_2, k_2$ are known and the unknowns are $p$ and $e$.

Proceed the mean least square regression from the system of $2n$ equations (because they are $n$ equations for each one of the two above symbolic equations).

The derivatives can be approximated by numerical computation as it was done above, or alternatively the integral computation in interest of robustness:

$p \int (1-{B\over k_2})Adt-e\int Bdt=-A+r_1 \int Adt$

$p \int (1-{B\over k_2})Adt -e \int Bdt=B-r_2 \int Bdt$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But I would appreciate if you can clarify bit more. In $\quad I_k=I_{k-1}+\frac12 (B_k+B_{k+1})(t_{k+1}-t_k)\quad\text{from}\quad k=2\quad\text{to}\quad k=n$ why isn't it $I_{k+1}=I_k+...$? .Also,I don't get how it was set to $I_1=0$.  How is it possible to fit $\quad Y(t)=r_2B(t)$ as  $\quad Y(t)=r_2\int B(t)$Also can you please explain  as to how $r_2\simeq \frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}Y_kB_k}{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(B_k)^2}$ was obtained. Was it similar to $(X^TX)${-1}X^TY$?

Comment: Also data is not as $\quad\begin{cases} A_1,A_2,...,A_k,...,A_n \\ B_1,B_2,...,B_k,...,B_n \\t_1,t_2,...,t_k,...,t_n\end{cases}$ It is similar to, $\quad\begin{cases} A_1+B_1+A_2+B_2,...,A_k+B_k,...,A_n+B_n \\ e(B_1+B_2,B_3+B_4,...,B_{k-1}+B_k,...,B_{n-1}+B_n) \\t_1,t_2,...,t_k,...,t_n\end{cases}$ With this data also is it possible to use the approach that you suggested?

Comment: I tried to understand your wording of the question and I asked you to clarify it. Apparently, your clarification was not sufficient to avoid a misunderstanding. I am sorry for that. I have not much time available.  I can't continue to waste time with a problem which wording remains ambiguous for me. So, I stop the discussion and I which you good luck.

Comment: If you want some examples of the use of numerical integration in fitting differential and/or integral equations, see https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-intégrales .

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there any other reference that I know that I can use to understand  numerical integration in fitting differential equations as the reference that you gave is not in a language familiar to me

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumericalIntegration.html ; http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumericalDifferentiation.html